# 2-D Vector with structs: How to store elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

Currently, I have a struct like this:

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Now, inside of a function, I am trying to declare a 2-D vector, and store elements inside of it.

```
void foo (){
    vector< vector<int> > v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            //I want to store the number '0' in each spot. Not sure how to do it.
            //Attempted method: v[i][j].push_back(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want the end result to be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0       . . . 
0       . . .
0       . . .
0       . . .
0       . . . 
0       . . .
0       . . .
0       . . .
0       . . .
```

Comment: What is the relationship between your vector of vector and your struct point?

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are static, use std::array instead

```
std::array<std::array<int,10>,10> v;
```

to store a value

```
v[x][y] = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option than doing it manually is using the correct constructor for your problem.

Using this

```
auto myvec = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(10, std::vector<int>(10, 0));
```

you get a 2D vector of 10 rows and 10 columns, initialized with 0 in each position.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

However i would also like to know how your mentioned struct relates to your question of initializing a 2D vector. Did you maybe mean to put your struct as base type of the inner vector?
Or do you just use your point struct as a mean to index your vector, in which case it wouldn't really be relevant for your question?